# Run jasperserver reports in different data sources

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Is there any way to run a single jasperserver report against different data sources? I want to be able to use a single report on jasperserver and just specify the data source from a Rails application. My temporary solution is to upload the same report, append the name of the environment, and use the appropriate data source. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637791/jasperserver-using-rest-to-run-a-report-with-data-source-specified-at-run-time) stackoverflow question but it doesn't have any answers.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have no defnitive answer, but it's a really good question since one of their brochures states that multiple data sources is a feature. It sounds like Subreports is the preferred method -  here's a clue I saw.

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/523748/multiple-database-connection-subreport

Comment: Please add it as a comment, if its not the answer to question.